# Changes to textcase and LaTeX kernel in the June 2022 release affecting uppercased captions

Tags: captions, latex3, textcase

With the **June 2022 release** of LaTeX, the case-changing commands formerly controlled by the `textcase` package have been absorbed into the kernel, as described in [ltnews35](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews35.pdf), page 4. A result of this change is that patches used to add exceptions to `textcase` no longer work. For example,

```
\patchcmd{\@uclcnotmath}{\@nonchangecase\ref}{\@nonchangecase\ref\@nonchangecase\eqref}{}{}
```

is no longer a solution to suppress case changing in the argument of the `amsmath` macro `\eqref` when it is used in an uppercased setting (e.g., an uppercased caption).

In addition, the new version gives me errors when `\label` is placed inside the argument to an uppercased `\caption`.

This mwe illustrates the problems I am encountering since updating to the **June 2022** release:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,caption,textcase}% need backward compatibility with old textcase

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1} #2}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{uppercase}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=uppercase,textformat=uppercase}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder={0 0 0},% 
    colorlinks=true,
}

% This patch added \eqref to the textcase exception list in the previous release
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@uclcnotmath}{\@nonchangecase\ref}{\@nonchangecase\ref\@nonchangecase\eqref}{}{} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\begin{equation}
S = k \ln w \label{eqn:1}
\end{equation}
See eqn.~\eqref{eqn:1} and Fig.~\ref{fig:1}.

\begin{figure}
% The first version does not work.  
%       first, the argument of \eqref is capitalized; 
%       second, \label throws errors when it is inside the caption
  \caption{A table caption, eqn.~\eqref{eqn:1}, $z = y^2$\label{fig:1}}

% This works, but requires two changes that might not be obvious to end users of the package involved
%  \caption{A table caption, eqn.~(\ref{eqn:1}), $z = y^2$}\label{fig:1}  
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Similar patching also allowed footnotes to be added to the exception list in the previous code.

I'd appreciate suggestions for resolving these issues within a class file, so that end-users of the class do not have to address these details when writing their documents.

Comment: `\label` is supposed to be safe, as is `\ref` , `\eqref` could be made safe with `\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl  { \eqref }` but `caption`  package is not expecting this somewhere and things going wrong. looking......

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \eqref must be made robust first.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer label still blows up though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hyperref seems to be a problem too ..

Comment: I removed that to simplify things...

Comment: unrelated but if you maintain a class then it would be good if you test it regularly with the dev-releases (simply compile with pdflatex-dev instead of pdflatex) then such problems are found earlier.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike.  That's helpful advice.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/881

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in the release

`LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 4`

Of LaTeX.

In addition a new command is available to add to the list of commands guarded from case changing.

```
 \AddToNoCaseChangeList{ \eqref }
```

is equivalent to the

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl  { \eqref }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

below and adds `\eqref` (presumably from `amsmath`) to the list.

---

**Original Answer**

This works, although I'm not suggesting you do this in your class, we'll adjust something so this is not necessary...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,caption}% need backward compatibility with old textcase

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{#1} #2}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=uppercase,textformat=uppercase}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{%
      \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
      \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##1##2\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
\begingroup
\def\label##1{\unexpanded{\label{##1}}}%
\def\eqref##1{\unexpanded{\eqref{##1}}}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\endgroup
   \@expl@text@uppercase@@n{\noexpand\unexpanded{#1}}}%
      \reserved@a
   }}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl  { \eqref }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder={0 0 0},% 
    colorlinks=true,
}

% This patch added \eqref to the textcase exception list in the previous release

\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\begin{equation}
S = k \ln w \label{eqn:1}
\end{equation}
See eqn.~\eqref{eqn:1} and Fig.~\ref{fig:1}.

\begin{figure}
% The first version does not work.  
%       first, the argument of \eqref is capitalized; 
%       second, \label throws errors when it is inside the caption
  \caption{A table caption, eqn.~\eqref{eqn:1}, $z = y^2$\label{fig:1}}

% This works, but requires two changes that might not be obvious to end users of the package involved
%  \caption{A table caption, eqn.~(\ref{eqn:1}), $z = y^2$}\label{fig:1}  
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks -- this code does resolve the problems, but I'll wait for the broader fix to avoid extra churn on the cls file.   A related issue: I also capitalize section headings (through `titlesec`), and when footnotes appear in the headings, it has become necessary to `\protect` them (`\robustify`won't do it).  This step was not necessary before the new release.  I find that simply adding ` \tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl  { \footnote }` to the above code doesn't suffice. I can post a separate question if it's not obvious how these problems are related.

Comment: @John probably related (somehow:-) If you have a small example could you add it to your question (formally supposed to make an issue at the latex github but adding it here will work fine...)

Comment: Thanks, David.  Actual, my bad -- I overlooked the need to add `\def\footnote##1{\unexpanded{\footnote{##1}}}%` and once I did that, your code resolved both issues.